# Running severals tests from severals bundle with Codeception

Tags: codeception

I ‘ve an issue with Codeception coupled with Symfony. I want to run several test suites from several bundles with only one run command

```
./bin/codeception run
```

The project structure looks like this :

```
my-bundle-application
  +--- app
  +--- bin
  +--- ...
  +--- codeception.yml // the main codeception file
  +--- tests
  +--- packages
  |    +--- my-bundle
  |         +--- my-core-bundle
  |               +--- app
  |               +--- bin
  |               +--- ...
  |               +--- src
  |                    +--- Controller
  |                    +--- Model
  |                    +--- ...
  |                    +--- MyCoreBundle.php
  |               +--- tests // codecetpion tests directory
  |                    +--- _data
  |                    +--- _support
  |                    +--- api
  |                    +--- _bootstrap.php
  |                    +--- api.suite.yml
  |               +--- codeception.yml // subfolder codeception file
  |               +--- composer.json (see below)
  |          +--- my-order-bundle
  |               +--- app
  |               +--- src
  |                    +--- Controller
  |                    +--- Model
  |                    +--- ...
  |                    +--- MyOrderBundle.php
  |               +--- bin
  |               +--- ...
  |               +--- tests
  |               +--- codeception.yml // subfolder codeception file
```

I want execute all test suite from my main bundle and also from my packages bundles. (my-bundle-application + my-core-bundle + my-order-bundle....)

I would like to know if it’s possible. I was thinking about the ‘include’ option in my main codeception.yml but things are not so simple and every test I’ve made give me the same error.

```
[Codeception\Exception\ConfigurationException]  
  Configuration file could not be found.          
  Run `bootstrap` to initialize Codeception.
```

Here is my main codeception.yml file :

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: ''
            user: ''
            password: ''
            dump: tests/_data/dump.sql
include:
    - MyBundle\CoreBundle // This give an error
```

The others Codeception files are similar without the include option.

and finally here is the composer.json of one of my sub Bundle

```
{
    "name": "my-bundle/my-core-bundle",
    "type": "symfony-bundle",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "description": "Bundle to manage core features.",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "MyBundle\\CoreBundle\\": "src/" } 
    },
...
}
```

Maybe I am not using Codeception correctly or there is no way to do this but I am not sure.
This github issue can also help : https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/319

Comment: Change `MyBundle\CoreBundle` to `MyBundle/CoreBundle`.

Comment: Have you read http://codeception.com/docs/08-Customization#One-Runner-for-Multiple-Applications ? Are you bundle test suites namespaced?

Comment: Hi, Thank for your help, I tried the first solution without success.

Comment: You are right, the composer.json of my sub-bundles define the namespace root to be in the ‘src’ folder which not contains codeception.yml. This is definitely a namespace issue. I am gonna try again modifying my bundles.